# How to override product search result block

Tags: blocks, magento-1, overrides, catalogsearch

I need a quick help, need to override

```
app\code\core\Mage\CatalogSearch\Block\Result.php
```

How do I do that in my module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**app/etc/modules/Package_CatalogSearch.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Package_CatalogSearch>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Package_CatalogSearch>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Now inside module,
    app/code/local/Package/CatalogSearch/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Package_CatalogSearch>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Package_CatalogSearch>
  </modules>

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalogsearch>
                <rewrite>
                    <result>Package_CatalogSearch_Block_Result</result>
                </rewrite>
            </catalogsearch>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Package/CatalogSearch/Block/Result.php** and a class has to be defined:

```
class Package_CatalogSearch_Block_Result extends Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Result
{
        // some code here
}
```